# How to run a cronjob in a Django app running on nginx uwsgi

Tags: django, nginx, cron, uwsgi

I have a django app running on a web server with nginx and uwsgi.

On my local server the crons are working.

I added it with `python3 manage.py crontab add` command.

I guess it doesn't work this way on the web server as it's not working when i try.

I can't find / figure out how to configure it properly.

Maybe someone can enlighten me ?

Thanks

Comment: crontab is not a Django command, afaik.  Normally you'd add something in `/etc/cron.d/`

Comment: i dont really understand. what is the something i have to add ?